# How to increase the perfomance of R in machine learning?

Tags: python, r, performance, machine-learning, regression

I am using both R and python(Anaconda).When it comes to modelling,R is taking more time for the same operation.Is there any method for parallel operations or multi threading in R?

Answer (score 1):

When using machine learning algorithms in R you can call some libraries that allow parallelization. In the example below the difference is huge.

You can call them like this (note that the '2' depends on your number of clusters):

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

This example is extracted from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf

```
> x <- iris[which(iris[,5] != "setosa"), c(1,5)]
> trials <- 10000
> ptime <- system.time({
+ r <- foreach(icount(trials), .combine=cbind) %dopar% {
+ ind <- sample(100, 100, replace=TRUE)
+ result1 <- glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1], family=binomial(logit))
+ coefficients(result1)
+ }
+ })[3]
> ptime
```

and is much faster than

```
> stime <- system.time({
+ r <- foreach(icount(trials), .combine=cbind) %do% {
+ ind <- sample(100, 100, replace=TRUE)
+ result1 <- glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1], family=binomial(logit))
+ coefficients(result1)
+ }
+ })[3]
> stime
```